# Reading files which are written using PartitionBy or BucketBy in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, partition-by

In Spark, when we read files which are written either using partitionBy or bucketBy, how spark identifies that they are of such sort (partitionBy/bucketBy) and accordingly the read operation becomes efficient ?
Can someone please explain. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Partitions are simply identified by subdirectories `/year=2020/month=01/` and discovered while scanning folder structure. The buckets are clusters under the partitions, see [pruning buckets](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/apache-spark-2.4.0-features-bucket-pruning/read) to know how Spark discovers bucketed columns.

Answer (score 3):

Two different things. Here https://mapr.com/blog/tips-and-best-practices-to-take-advantage-of-spark-2-x/ an excellent excerpt from poor little mapR, let's hope HP makes something of it. Reading this will give you the whole context. Excellent read BTW.

> Two different things in reality:
>
> - When **partition** filters are present, the Catalyst optimizer **pushes down** the partition filters from the given query. The scan reads only
>     the directories that match the partition filters, thus reducing disk
>     I/O. Performance improvement in relation to query, sec.
> - **Bucketing** is another data organization technique that groups data with the same bucket value across a fixed number of “buckets.” This
>     can improve performance in **wide transformations and joins** by
>     avoiding “shuffles.”

Comment: Also useful to know from the blog, in the section on Parquet files under Bucketing Tips: "_Partitioning should only be used with columns that have a limited number of values; bucketing works well when the number of unique values is large. Columns which are used often in queries and provide high selectivity are good choices for bucketing._" While this may on the surface seem to be of concern when writing not reading, if one finds that reads are taking a long time, these are things to look at.